# How to get ntp to use gpsd to update system date/time with a large offset

Tags: ntpd, gpsd

I have a GPS connected to my system, and if I change system time to be ahead/behind GPS time by less than 4 hours, **`ntpd`** ensures that the system time is updated to match that of the GPS. If, however, that offset is beyond 4 hours, no update takes place.

I have ensured to run **`ntpd`** with the `-g` option, but it still doesn't work, unless I use normal ntp servers, for example having `server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst` in **/etc/ntp.conf**. Let us, however, assume that the system in question will not have internet access during normal operation.

The other relevant settings in that file are:

```
server 127.127.28.0 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.420 refid GPS

server 127.127.28.1 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 prefer
fudge 127.127.28.1 refid GPS1
```

(source: **`gpsd`** manpage)

I even added `tinker panic 0` to that config, just to make sure, but still no luck.

Comment: Did I get it correctly that you want to make it working without internet connectivity at all?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to go for a *work-around*... I used **[chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/)**.

Here is what I have in the config file at `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf` to use the GPS as the reference clock ([source](http://gpsd.berlios.de/gpsd.html)):

```
refclock SHM 0
```

Then, to actually get **`chrony`** to do large offset adjustments, instead of the normal gradual ones, I added this to the same config file:

```
makestep 1000 -1
```

That means that the step adjustment will happen when the hardware clock is off by at least a 1000 seconds. `-1` means try as many times as it takes to get to match the reference clock.

I left the other settings intact, as provided by Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 3):

4 hours limit checking is implemented in ntpd/refclock_shm.c (ntp-4.2.8p7) and 
setting value '1' to flag1 in /etc/ntp.conf seems to stop this checking.

```
 server 127.127.28.0 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 prefer
 fudge 127.127.28.0 refid GPS stratum 4
 fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.113  # coarse processing delay offset
 fudge 127.127.28.0 flag1 1      # ignore difference limit
```

I am running ntpd 4.2.8p3 on a RaspberryPi.

Comment: Although I have my concerns whether it is the same code of `ntpd` that may have been running in 2012 this likely does clear up from where the limit comes from (+1).