# How to ignore "certificate is not yet valid" errors

Tags: openvpn

I have systems that sometimes lose time drastically due to low RTC battery voltage such that the system time lies outside these boundaries (`/etc/openvpn/certificate`):

```
Not Before: Jun 18 16:40:18 2012 GMT
Not After : Jun 16 16:40:18 2023 GMT
```

I would still like to have these systems connect to the VPN, so I don't get messages like:

> Feb  6 13:50:58 hostname ovpn-client[2217]: VERIFY ERROR: depth=1, error=certificate is not yet valid: /C=ZA/ST=GA/L=Johannesburg/O=Embedded_IQ/CN=Embedded_IQ_CA/emailAddress=info@example.com

I can avoid this problem by simply correcting the datetime on these systems, but it's not always feasible... these are remote systems.

Comment: Why don't you just set up an [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client?

Comment: I do have it set up, but when datetime is too far off, [ntpd refuses to correct it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52002).

Comment: run `ntpdate` every now and then (rather than `ntpd`), it will correct even big errors.

Comment: You could set up a little `init` script that sets the date to a reasonable fixed minimum (say, February 17, 2013) if it is set to anything older. Then `ntp` synchronization etc. can take over.

Comment: @umläute Use `ntpd -g` to allow the first adjustment to be Big.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply synchronize the time using `ntp` right before your are starting the connection, e.g. by using a little script to connect to the VPN:

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpdate ntp.example.com
openvpn --config myvpn.conf
```

Comment: I set system time using gpsd. These systems are placed on vehicles, so they won't always have a nice view of the sky.

Comment: but in order to connect to the VPN, they have to see the vpn-server...so you could even run an ntp-server on the vpn-server....

Comment: The connection to the VPN server does not need to be that reliable, but the system time needs to be.